# WSO2 ESB - How to get and set cookies in WSDL calls in

Tags: cookies, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB and want to connect 2 web services together - on a timer pull data from one service and push it to another.

The problem is that one of the services authenticates callers with cookies. You first need to call a GetSession method with the username and password. The response to this call sets a cookie. Then with this cookie you make other calls.

I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation, how can I get a cookie from the result of one call and set it for a subsequent call. Is it at all achievable? If so - how?

Here is my sequence code:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleName" trace="enable">
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <Body>
               <GetSessionWithCredentials xmlns="blabla">
                  <User>bla</User>
                  <Password>bla</Password>
               </GetSessionWithCredentials>
            </Body>
         </Envelope>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <call>
      <endpoint key="conf:/Tracker"></endpoint>
   </call>
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <GetTrackingList xmlns="blabla"></GetTrackingList>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Cookie" expression="$trp:Cookie"></property>
   <call>
      <endpoint key="conf:/Tracker"></endpoint>
   </call>
   <log level="full"></log>
</sequence>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get Cookie header : `<property name="Cookie" expression="$trp:Cookie"/>`
If you want to get one cookie and it's value, use xpath expression with 'substring' for exemple

set cookie header with value JSESSIONID=1 : `<property name="Cookie" value="JSESSIONID=1" scope="transport"/>`

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Michel! But I couldn't get it working. I appended the sequence code to the question, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? The second call returns an error of "No valid session".

Comment: By the way, is there a way to debug the headers in ESB? Thank you

Comment: with <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Cookie" expression="$trp:Cookie"></property>, you're are just defining a property named 'Cookie' and it's value is what you find in Cookie header...  In ESB_HOME/bin you will find tcpmon, use it to debug http headers

Comment: It worked, but I had to user $trp.Set-Cookie instead of $trp.Cookie!

Comment: I try this with WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and not work for me. I recieve null value with $trp.Set-Cookie